# How to parametrize azureSubscription in azure devops template task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use parameters in Azure Devops templates.
I can print any parameter inside the template.
But when I use parameter in a template with any task that requires azure subscription that will make the pipeline always fail with

> "The pipeline is not valid. Job myDeployment: Step input
>   azureSubscription references service connection $(mySubscription)
>   which could not be found."

Example of pipeline and template below.
Is there any way to path azure Subscription to the template?**strong text**

*pipeline.yml*

```
- stage: myStage
  pool: windows
  variables: 
    - name: azureSubscription
      value: mySubscription
    - name: keyVaultName
      name: myKeyVauld

  jobs: 
    deployment: myDeployment
    strategy: 
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - template: myTemplate.yml
            parameters: 
              subscription: $(azureSubscription) # changing this to literal will work but not what I need
              vault: $(keyVaultName)
```

*myTemplate.yml*

```
parameters:
- name: subscription
  type: string
  default: ''
- name: vault
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:

- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.subscription }}'
    keyVaultName: '${{ parameters.vault }}'
    secretsFilter: myKey
```

Comment: Thank you for asking this question !

Comment: The syntax '${{ parameters.paramName }}' in above template.yml  now works in latest Azure DevOps, FYI

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a known issue / limitation. You have to pass the Azure subscription as a literal. No way around it that I know of, unfortunately.

It's been a point of discussion for literally years on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1307

Comment: Note that today, this is no longer true: you can now both use variables and parameters as a value for azureSubscription.

Comment: I read through the GitHub referenced. It looks like it needs to be passed through a variable - you can't just refer to a variable group and have it work.

Answer (score -2):

You need to go to **Project setting** -> *Pipelines section* -> **Service connections** and  create a **[Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)** for **Azure Resource Manager**, choose between **Service principal** and **Managed identity** authentication type.

[image]

After you can use the name of created Service Connection in your YAML file in `azureSubscription` parameter.

[image]

Comment: "mySubscription" is an existing working subscription. The issue is only when I pass it to the template as variable.