# AzureSubcription and azureContainerRegistry connection from Library

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a Docker Compose in my pipeline and Azure created the code. The `azureSubscription` and the `azureContainerRegistry` connection are very clear.

[image]

I tried to replace them with variable from the Library but when the pipeline starts I immediately get an error.

> There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job Build: Step DockerCompose1 input azureSubscriptionEndpoint references service connection $(AzureSubscription) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz. Job Build: Step DockerCompose2 input azureSubscriptionEndpoint references service connection $(AzureSubscription) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to [https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."](https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.%22)

[image]

Basically, Azure DevOps can't replace the variable with the value for those particular parameters. I don't want to send around those configurations for obviuos reasons.

I saw some old posts where Microsoft said this was an issue in DevOps. Is this issue still there? Is there any way to move those values in the Libray or a variables?

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue. It have to be an literal or variables defined in YAML. It cannot be variable provied via variable group for instance. Please check these topics:

- [How to parametrize azureSubscription in azure devops template task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437249/how-to-parametrize-azuresubscription-in-azure-devops-template-task)
- [Azure subscription endpoint ID cannot be provided through a variable in build definition YAML file](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1307)
- [Azure subscription endpoint ID cannot be provided through a variable in build definition YAML file](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-subscription-endpoint-id-cannot-be-provided/1073702)